# Conducting Cluster Validation by comparing with the Ground Truth

Tags: cluster-computing, cluster-analysis

How should we carry out cluster validation in terms of average error index or precision or recall?
My doubt is that say using a dataset D and following my algorithm I get 6 clusters labelled c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6 with 50,60,30,40,10,10,10 no of elements in each cluster respectively .

In the dataset D,the actual cluster labels are 1,2,3....6 with 55,45,5,35,10,60 no of elements in each cluster respectively.

Is it necessary that my cluster label c1 must correspond to actual cluster label 1, c2 to 2, c3 to 3,....and so on?

How will I calculate average error index in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Any good clustering toolkit (e.g. ELKI) should come with *dozens* of validation measures. ARI is probably one of the most popular.

Anyway, there is *tons* of literature on that; any textbook on cluster analysis should cover the topic of validation. Any any decent software should include such validation measures.

Maybe you can read up on these, and then come back with a more precise question?

After all, the question you have just asked is already answered in literature. You are not the first to notice that there isn't always a 1:1 correspondence of clusters when comparing two results. ARI is one, the general principle is to look at *pairs of objects* (a pair exists iff the two elements are in the same cluster) and compute precision, recall etc. of these pairs.

Comment: how can we validate clusters based on density?which measure will be the best to validate the results of density based clusterings?

Comment: I don't know. I don't think a density-based validation makes a lot of sense, because it will then only report that density-based clustering gives the best density-based clusters. What a surprise.
The most reasonable way of validation is by actually *using* the result. There is no use in having a result that looks good on some measure, but doesn't work in practise.

Comment: If you have ground truth, all of these measures can be used to *evalute* density based clustering though. The measures don't use density, but if you have e.g. a DBSCAN clustering and "truth" labels, ARI is a popular measure.